# Sack the [career-development] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, blocklist-request

There is, apparently, a [career-development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/career-development) tag. It has two questions, both of which are closed and likely to get roomba'd soon; there is no tag usage guidance or wiki. Questions about career development are necessarily off-topic for Stack Overflow, so this tag simply can't be used for a question that meets the site's standards.

However, the tag has 345 watchers, suggesting that there have probably been a significant number of bad questions which were posted with this tag and later deleted.

I believe this tag should be deleted and blocklisted, to avoid new users thinking that questions about career development might be on-topic because a tag for them exists. In my opinion, the tag meets the description given in the [blocklist-request](/questions/tagged/blocklist-request) meta tag:

> Tags must be "quite bad" to be blocklisted. Generally, these are tags that could *never* convey any useful information or are actively harmful to the site.

Comment: There are 2,697 questions with this tag and all of them deleted. It attracts a lot of off-topic and spam questions. I am in favour of blocking it, but first maybe let's see if it will get deleted and recreated.

Comment: Sadly, this is one of the many stuck tags. It won't be deleted. The source of the bug has been identified, but when we'll get devtime, if any, is unclear

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine does it have anything to do with tag synonyms, considering [this tag has 4](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/career-development/synonyms): [tag:career]. [tag:career-advice], [tag:employment], [tag:job-hunting]? (Perhaps unsynomizing them might also help reduce the probability of this tag being used?)

Comment: @AndrewT. Sadly, no. It's related to collective articles, in a way where not even mods can bypass it.

Comment: The only way to "solve" the problem here is to blacklist, but we'll need an error message prior to escalating

Comment: Another one for the dustbin: [tag:developers].

Comment: The [career-development] tag was fired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This tag (along with many other tags created on draft Articles) has now been cleaned up.

As indicated in the comments, this was one of several tags that was "stuck" due to being on a draft Article. There were a few issues involved here; originally, Article drafts allowed authors to create tags without needing the [create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege or preventing blocked tags from being added; in addition, the tags would not be cleaned up by the system automatically, because they were present on Article drafts and could not be removed by anyone without editing permissions on those Articles.

The Collectives team recently went through and did a cleanup of tags created on Article drafts. I worked with the mods to get lists of the affected tags, and shared them with the Collectives team for cleanup; in all, we deleted about 79 tags. The reputation requirement is also now being enforced for tag creation via Articles, as is the blocklist. The Collectives team is also working on making changes to the Article draft process to prevent this sort of problem in the future.

I've followed up with the site moderators, and confirmed that tag block requests for these formerly "stuck" tags are no longer necessary (unless the tags actually end up being recreated) now that the underlying problem has been addressed. Thank you all for your patience!